Can I use style-dictionary functionality without flushing the result into a output file?
I am creating a design system using Storybook and style-dictionary. My tokens are saved in tokens.json, which looks like this:
{
  "global": {
    "colors": {
      "default": {
        "white": {
          "value": "#ffffff",
          "type": "color"
        },
        "black": {
          "value": "#000000",
          "type": "color"
        },
        "red": {
          "value": "#ff0000",
          "type": "color"
        },
         ...
        }
     }
  }
}

I am exporting these tokens using style-dictionary into scss files. For this purpose I have build-tokens.js script that, apart from that, also manually edits the tokens before flushing them into a new scss file (they need some extra polishing before exporting).

First, I am registering a custom format:

StyleDictionary.registerFormat({
  name: `customFormat`,
  formatter: function({ dictionary, file }) {
    let editedTokens = ``
    // ...
    // manual polishing of dictionary.tokens
    return editedTokens
   }
})


Then, I am using it like this:

const sd = StyleDictionary.extend({
  source: ['src/tokens/tokens.json'],
  platforms: {
    scss: {
      transforms: [
        'ts/descriptionToComment',
        'ts/size/px',
        'ts/opacity',
        'ts/size/lineheight',
        'ts/type/fontWeight',
        'ts/resolveMath',
        'ts/size/css/letterspacing',
        'ts/typography/css/shorthand',
        'ts/border/css/shorthand',
        'ts/shadow/css/shorthand',
        'ts/color/css/hexrgba',
        'ts/color/modifiers',
        'name/cti/kebab'
      ],
      buildPath: 'build/scss/',
      files: [
        {
          destination: 'tokens.scss',
          format: 'scss/variables'
        },
        {
          destination: 'tokensForStorybook.scss',
          format: 'tokensForStorybook'   // <------------ here it is applied
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})

sd.cleanAllPlatforms()
sd.buildAllPlatforms()

My question is, can I somehow omit the exporting part of the script? Could I, for example, use it only as a "function library"? I would like to use this "polishing part" in my other script, without the need of running sd.buildAllPlatforms().
